# Reliable file sharing

Tags: network-attached-storage, file-sharing

We need a reliable file sharing solution to support large number of files (10M+) available to multiple computers (like web farm for image library).

I've came up with next solutions:

1. Use storage cloud (private or public like Amazon S3)
2. Build (Windows) cluster for file sharing with attached SAN

Do you have any better solution for this requirements?

Comment: What kind of resources do you have available to you?

Comment: 2x Windows Server 2008 R2 with access to SAN

Comment: You don't want reliable file sharing. If it goes down at 3PM daily you'll be able to set your watch by it reliably. What you want is resilient file sharing. Captain Pedantic signing off!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've got the answer already in your hands with a pair of 2K8 servers on a shared SAN. I'd suggest you set them up with cluster services and simply create one of more shares. Obviously you may have to add new disks, create new LUNs etc but it's a very straightforward solution, uses existing kit (always a good thing) and will perform really pretty well, faster than any cloud I'd imagine as I'm sure your LAN will be quicker than your internet links.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an intranet solution (i.e. inside your company's firewall) a SAN or a fast NAS is a good way to go. For external access, you could use S3, or Google Storage (still in beta - up to 1TB available), or similar such services. Bear in mind the bandwidth costs! The more people access and the larger the files, the more you pay.