# Complex structure with a "shared image folder" in multiple regions and or datacenters

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-server, rsync, network-attached-storage, file-sharing

Allow me to give you some details and background to understand the reasons and the whole issue here. Of course, any suggestion/feedback on the below structure **is very appreciated**.

Also, I am not affiliated with any of the companies that might see below or imagine regarding the provided services.

I am on a project to "design" a good plan for a company.

They have 500+ websites that all use the same database (MySQL behind) and they target globally. 
All the websites have images which have to be common to each other. Otherwords, all the websites use the same images (- or want at least)

> Eg.
>   website1.com/image.jpg,
>   website2.com/image.jpg
>
> website1.com/image-de.jpg
>   website2.com/image-de.jpg

As you can understand the images are GEOtargeted, but the names remain the same across all these websites for quicker managing.

However, they didn't "design" it well, and the latency between the servers and the management of the images are a complete disaster after a while.

So, in a nutshell,

3 Continents with one server and one dedicated MySQL server per continent. 
One developer server with MySQL in the office. 
On top of them, a Cloudflare load balancer to distribute the traffic correctly per region and per "server's health".

```
                          Global load balancer 
                                  |
    |                      |                   |             
    V                      V                   V       
  Region1                Region2            Region3       "Office"      
    |                      |                   |          Sends ONLY
    V                      V                   V
 WebServer1 <-rsync-> WebServer2 <-rsync-> WebServer3 <- DevServer
    |                       |                  |          
    V                       V                  V          
 DBMS-MySQL  <-rsync-> DBMS-MySQL<-rsync-> DBMS-MySQL <- DBMS
```

Be aware, that it might be a case to put a second server in one region depending on the traffic volume. 
So, the "local" structure will be

```
Global load balancer 
      |
      V
  Region1 -> Local load balancer 
                        |
       Server:local-1 <- -> Server:local-2
           |                    |
            ->   MySQL server <-
```

Backups per continent in the server and a separate S3 instance and the worse case scenario the dev-server is the final backup.

Now, think an image folder like a big "image-basket".
So, how can the "image-basket" be commonly attached to EVERY website?

All the servers will use (i think it would do the trick easy) `rsync` per 15to30mins in case to re-syncronize themselves for core files like the "HTML/CSS files etc."

Do I have a big overhead here?

Is there any other solution to "keep the servers updated all the time" ?

Of course, one will be the primary, and as I believe the major-first-primary server will be the developer server that hosts the essentials like administration panels etc. So, after the "push" the dev-server will "push" or "rsync" everything to all the three Regions-servers.

As you can understand, it is going to be a huge issue if I "rsync" the /image/ folder. We have to talk about 500+ /image/ folders of aprx. (right now) 20 GB each. So we need 500*20GB = 10.000GB extra for the images.. This is not a case as you can understand.

1) One "dirty" solution might be, to host in one server all the images, and every website using an HTTP request to get the correct images. 
Pretty **bad solution** because you might DDos your own application in high volume traffic hours.

2) In my opinion and point of view, the /image/ folder has to be in a separate instance or "whatever-is-that", to be used rapidly on every single server, in other words, to every single website. Is there any service out there that can be bind 3 at least webserver in different regions? I didn't find anything close to that yet.

At least, do you think any solution for the "sharing-image-basket" issue?

There was a question with something similar: [Reliable file sharing](https://serverfault.com/questions/190393/reliable-file-sharing) but as I see and understand, his case is different.

## UPDATE-Clarifications

1) A request for (e.g.) /image/foo.png should always return the same file regardless of which site is being accessed, and regardless of which region.

2) What are the geographic references of the regions: 3 different continents. So, three different "private networks" if we are talking about Digital Ocean, or three different VPCs if we are talking about AWS, etc.

3) How much traffic is there: Traffic is not related to the solution. Think a big increasing volume of traffic and requests. It doesn't make sense to have a solution for low traffic and when the traffic is double+ to "design it" or trying to upgrade the CPU/RAM/STORARE-GB. That's why I propose "local" load balancer for a region, with a "replica" machine to distribute and bypass the big volume of traffic.

Comment: Clarifications: a request for (e.g.) `/image/foo.png` should always return the same file regardless of which site is being accessed, and regardless of which region?    What are the geographic references of the regions (e.g. New York, Sydney, London)?   How much traffic is there?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yep, of course. I think I mentioned that.  foo.png is the same file regardless which website from any region accessed it.
The geographic references of the regions are not a case.  Say Canada, Sydney, Frankfurt, however, it does not need any more clarification about it. Just think it like completely different continents.  So, three different "private networks" if we are talking about Digital Ocean, or three different VPC if we are talking about AWS, etc.

Comment: That's why I asked for clarification. Perhaps I should have said "confirmation." I thought that was what you were saying, but wanted to be sure I had a correct understanding, since you mentioned "geo-targeted" (which might imply that foo was always a picture of a foo but not necessarily the same foo; similarly, the "-de" suffix could have referred to either a caption language or a viewer location). Regarding regions, I wasn't fishing for proprietary information, just a general idea.  Peru, Ukraine, Japan would potentially be a much different solution than the regional centers that I suggested.

Comment: Note also that traffic *is* a significant factor in your design consideration, because a pull-through CDN will give you more consistent performance due to object popularity with high traffic than it would give with the same design but low traffic.  I have a global image site in CloudFront that averages a 92% hit rate across all objects, with the top 50 objects averaging 99.75%.  The site would not perform as well as it does if the traffic were lower.  It currently uses a single S3 origin.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot no worries. i didn't say that u fishing, neither that your comments were bad

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot w8 w8, what do u mean u have a "global image site in CloudFront" ?   Can I host directly images on CloudFront ?   

I think, I have to host the images in a server or instance and "CloudFront" will be attach on the server, and serves the images to the visitors for me.Works like MAXCDN/Cloudflare/etc.

Comment: The site is provisioned in CloudFront but the content is in an S3 bucket ("it currently uses a single S3 origin") in us-west-2.  I've contemplated replicating the content from Oregon to S3 in Frankfurt or London now that Lambda@Edge allows region-based origin selection but right now my numbers look pretty good as it stands because my traffic is high enough that I don't see a lot of cache misses.  Statistically, you need a decent amount of traffic for that to happen because a CDN will can unpopular objects before they expire.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot because I was thinking to use the DigitalOcean's services for webservers. Do you think that I can easily attach the S3 instance on the DigitalOcean's machines ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70616/discussion-between-michael-sqlbot-and-greg).